# c# HttpClient System.Net.WebException: Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером

Tags: c#, httpclient

Пытаюсь проверить большой список доменов на валидность.
Пробую делать это в многопоточном режиме.
Принцип роботы:
Отправляю GET запрос к сайту, затем проверяю его HTML код.
Код:

```
 httpClient loadingPage = new httpClient();
    private async void Button_Click_1Async(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int j = 0;
        IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(p => AllDomains.Content = Convert.ToString(j++));
        IProgress<string> progress1 = new Progress<string>(p => good.Text += p + "\n");
        IProgress<string> progress2 = new Progress<string>(p => bad.Text += p + "\n");
        IProgress<string> progress3 = new Progress<string>(p => Catch.Text += p + "\n");
         

        string[] arrString = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\domain.txt");
        int arrStringCountForThread = (arrString.Length / 20);

        int maxConcurrency = 30; // сколько одновременно может работать потоков
        using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] NEWarrString = new string[arrStringCountForThread];
                    //Разделяем arrString на 20 массивов равного размера 
                    // каждый tasks получает 1/20 элементов массива

                    Array.Copy(arrString, (i * arrStringCountForThread), NEWarrString, 0, arrStringCountForThread);
                    tasks.Add(loadingPage.ProcessPage(NEWarrString, progress, progress1, progress2, progress3, semaphore)); // запуск I/O-bound операции
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех
        }
    }
```

httpClient.cs

```
 searshCMS searsh = new searshCMS();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public async Task ProcessPage(string[] url, IProgress<string> progress, IProgress<string> progress1, IProgress<string> progress2, IProgress<string> progress3, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
    {  string urllink = null;
        // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(url.Length));
        for (int i = 0; i < url.Length - 1; i++)
        {urllink = url[i];
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                
                string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url[i]);
                searsh.SearchCMS(url[i], html, progress, progress1, progress2, progress3);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                progress3.Report(Convert.ToString(e));
            }
        }
    }
```

В  searsh.SearchCMS(url[i], html, progress, progress1, progress2, progress3); передаётся HTML страницы для дальнейшей обработки.

В методе ProcessPage  появляется очень много исключений

```
catch (Exception e)
            {
                progress3.Report(Convert.ToString(e));
            }
```

Например:

> https://hairline.hu
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса. ---> System.Net.WebException: Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера 79.172.205.80:443
> в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> в System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> в System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
> --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
> в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> в System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
> --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

При этом в браузере https://hairline.hu загружается.
В исключение падает примерно 50% всех доменов, большинство из них рабочее

Comment: Браузер шлет дополнительные заголовки с запросом, может в этом и проблема?

Comment: @tym32167, если повторно перезапустить программу этот же домен может загрузиться нормально

Comment: Может быть у вас проблема с ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit  вот тут описано много интересного про HttpClient https://habr.com/ru/post/424873/

Comment: Указал ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
Ничего не изменилось

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` если у вас .NET Framework 4.6 и выше, вообще не надо указывать. А в .NET Core оно вообще не работает. Еще скажите, какая у вас Windows? Она поддерживает TLS 1.2?

Comment: @aepot, Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Вы как-то странно поступили с кодом. Я узнаю комментарии, кажется я не так давно их писал.

Вот так попробуйте

```cs
private async void Button_Click_1Async(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(p => AllDomains.Content = Convert.ToString(j++));
    IProgress<string> progress1 = new Progress<string>(p => good.Text += p + "\n");
    IProgress<string> progress2 = new Progress<string>(p => bad.Text += p + "\n");
    IProgress<string> progress3 = new Progress<string>(p => Catch.Text += p + "\n");

    string[] arrString = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\domain.txt");

    int maxConcurrency = 30; // сколько одновременно может работать потоков
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string s in arrString)
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            tasks.Add(loadingPage.ProcessPage(s, progress, progress1, progress2, progress3, semaphore)); // запуск I/O-bound операции
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task ProcessPage(string url, IProgress<string> progress, IProgress<string> progress1, IProgress<string> progress2, IProgress<string> progress3, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        string html;
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompleteionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        searsh.SearchCMS(url, html, progress, progress1, progress2, progress3);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        progress3.Report(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Вот теперь будет работать 30 одновременных запросов.

Я проверил дважды, указанный вами адрес выдает страницу нормально. Вот этим кодом в консольном приложении проверил. Скорее всего проблема в вашей Windows.

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://hairline.hu");
        Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится большой HTML.

Comment: Использовал ваш код:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса. ---> System.Net.WebException: Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера 107.180.115.186:443

Comment: Из 100 сайтов ~40 ушли в исключение, при этом если программу перезапустить - те сайты что перед этим уходили в исключение могут отработать нормально, а те что работали нормально уйти в исключение. Вообще не понимаю с чем это связанно

Comment: @user54353 что делает метод `SearchCMS`? Как долго он работает? Что там внутри? Что будет, если одновременных запросов указать к примеру не 30, а 10?

Comment: @user54353 обновил код в ответе

Comment: Пробовал 1\5\10\50 одновременных запросов, весь  SearchCMS это:
 if (str.IndexOf(line) != -1)
            {
                progress1.Report(link);
               
            }

Comment: Все тоже самое, завтра попробую на другом ПК, может и правда проблема в ОС

Comment: проблема оказалась в канале передачи данных. Подключился через другого провайдера и все заработало. Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @user54353 если вам помог мой ответ, подалуйста отметьте его галочкой.